# CONCAT but return blanks for empty fields - MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
MySQL 8
```

What I would like to do, is return ***full_name*** from a table, with ***first_name***, ***middle_name***, ***last_name***, but would like a single space in between them, and no space if any of the values are either null or an empty string.

I tried:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(
    IF(LENGTH(first_name),first_name,' '), 
    IF(LENGTH(middle_name),middle_name,' '), 
    IF(LENGTH(last_name),last_name,'')
    ) as name from users
```

However, this works ONLY if the middle_name is either empty or null. If the middle_name has a value, then it splices them all together, with no spaces.

So, ***John Doe***, returns ***John Doe***, and ***John F Doe***, returns ***JohnFDoe***.

I am using LENGTH as I believe it works for both NULL and empty string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of functions that really help with this, concat_ws and nullif.

```
concat_ws(' ',nullif(first_name,''),nullif(middle_name,''),nullif(last_name,''))
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I0IgrYMk)

The nullif returns null for the component if it is either empty or null.  Then concat_ws joins with spaces all its non-null arguments.

Comment: This works for empty values, nut not NULL. nullif(first_name,'') is comparing first_name to an empty string

Comment: that's correct; if first_name is either "" or null, the nullif returns null, so concat_ws ignores that argument and doesn't add an extra space to separate it.  added a fiddle demonstrating.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(
    IF(LENGTH(first_name),first_name,' '), 
    IF(LENGTH(middle_name),middle_name + ' ',' '), 
    IF(LENGTH(last_name),last_name,'')
    ) as name from users
```

If that doesn't work, you could try to set this up outside and above the given block:

```
CASE WHEN middle_name = middle_name THEN middle_name + ' ' ELSE '' END
```